# how to remove the even listener after the array is finished

Tags: javascript

I'm playing with JS but I'm just a beginner. I guess this way  works out for me the best. I want to start a dialog as an event listener by creating new divs with elements of the conversation. I also set the timeInteval after the function is called. How can I avoid displaying "the end" numerous times after the button is clicked again.

```
  <button id="btn">Start the conversation</button>
```

```
  const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");

  const dialog = [
  " Hello",
  " Hi",
  " You're new here?",
  " Yes.",
  " Would you like a drink?",
  " Sure.",
  ];

  let i = 0;

  btn.addEventListener("click", generateConversation);

  // setTimeout(generateConversation, 1000);

 function generateConversation() {
  let newSay = document.createElement("div");
  newSay.innerText = dialog[i];
  container.appendChild(newSay);
  i++;
  setInterval(generateConversation, 1000);

  if (i >= dialog.length) {
    newSay.innerText = "The End";
    intervalId = setInterval(generateConversation, 1000);
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
```

I applied the suggestions by Pedro but the code keeps running. How to stop it when the dialog.length is reached?

Comment: Thank you all for help and sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Did the code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only run a EventListener one time you can pass an option of `"once": true`:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", generateConversation, { once: true });
```

Since you only want the conversation to start when the button is clicked move `setInterval` to inside `generateConversation` and save it to a variable, it returns an id that can be used to delete it:

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <button id="btn">Start the conversation</button>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <script>
 const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");

  const dialog = [
  " Hello",
  " Hi",
  " You're new here?",
  " Yes.",
  " Would you like a drink?",
  " Sure.",
  ];

  let i = 0;

  btn.addEventListener("click", generateConversation, { once: true });


  function generateConversation() {
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    let newSay = document.createElement("div");
    newSay.innerText = dialog[i];
    container.appendChild(newSay);
    i++;
    if (i >= dialog.length) {
      newSay.innerText = "The End";
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, 1000);
  }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but after I remove the event listener the function goes on and on

Comment: What do you mean by that? just remove it after `newSay.innerText = "The End";` in your if statement.

Comment: How to stop this function from running? If there were no 
  setInterval(generateConversation, 1000); it would stop. How can I stop this function after it is called and completed?

Comment: Oh so you also want to stop the `setInterval`

Comment: now I think, I do :)

Comment: Try the code now.

Comment: function generateConversation() {
  let newSay = document.createElement("div");
  newSay.innerText = dialog[i];
  container.appendChild(newSay);
  i++;
  setInterval(generateConversation, 1000);

  if (i >= dialog.length) {
    newSay.innerText = "The End";
    intervalId = setInterval(generateConversation, 1000);
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}  // You mean like this  - the End is displayed incessantly

Comment: Try all code now...

Comment: { once: true } That was a great tip, Pedro. Thanks a lot. I've already used it with a Blackjack game to start the game only once.

Answer (score 1):

You have assing set interval to a variable like this

```
var myVar = setInterval(generateConversation, 1000);
```

and then for clear setInterval pass that var in

```
clearTimeout(myVar);
```

for start chat on button click, you have to put this line inside the button click event

```
var myVar = setInterval(generateConversation, 1000);
```

check the below update code.

```
 $("#btn").click(function(){
      myVar = setInterval(generateConversation, 1000);
    });
```

here is the working demo hope it's easy to understand how clearInterval is worked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <button id="btn">Start the conversation</button>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <script>
 const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");

  const dialog = [
  " Hello",
  " Hi",
  " You're new here?",
  " Yes.",
  " Would you like a drink?",
  " Sure.",
  ];

  let i = 0;

  

  // setTimeout(generateConversation, 1000);
var myVar;

  function generateConversation() {
  let newSay = document.createElement("div");
  newSay.innerText = dialog[i];
  container.appendChild(newSay);
  i++;
  if (i >= dialog.length) {
    newSay.innerText = "The End";
   myStopFunction();
  }
  }
function myStopFunction() {
  clearTimeout(myVar);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(){
      myVar = setInterval(generateConversation, 1000);
    }); 
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code work well. Thanks. Neeraj. But the function starts without the event listener clicked. How to fix that?

Comment: ok wait let me check that.

Comment: @TomDev check now